# DataTables table plugin for jquery: how to set a css class for tr and td

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to set a css class to a row using the DataTables, query plugin for tables.

I managed to set the class on the `tr` tag when the initialization was complete with:

```
"fnInitComplete": function(oSettings) {
                                for (var i = 0, iLen = oSettings.aoData.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                                    oSettings.aoData[i].nTr.className = "myClass";
                                }
                            },
```

I want to set a callback for each new row, and set to `tr` class `a` and to `td` class `b`

I know how to add a class, and i need to set a class!

```
"fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aaData, iDisplayIndex) {
                                console.log(aaData);
                                $('tr', nRow).addClass('a');
                                $('td:eq(0)', nRow).addClass('b');
                                $('td:eq(1)', nRow).addClass('b');
                                $('td:eq(2)', nRow).addClass('b');
                                $('td:eq(3)', nRow).addClass('b');
                                return nRow;
                            },
```

this is what troubles me:

`$('tr', nRow).addClass('a');`

I don't know how to set a class to a `tr` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs [(fnRowCallback)](http://datatables.net/ref#fnRowCallback) the `nRow` represents a `TR` element

so this should do:

```
$(nRow).addClass('a');
```

---

If you want to add class to certain row N# you can use this(just build a proper selector):

```
$("tr:eq(" + rowNumber+ ")").addClass('a');
```

the string should look like this `"tr:eq(1)"`

Comment: yes, i also figured it out, later :)) it was nRow :)) because it's a callback :))

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct then your issue might be in this line:

```
$('tr', nRow).addClass('a');
```

Because it equates to writing:

```
$(nRow).find('tr').addClass('a');
```

And you shouldn't be able to find a TR inside another TR (unless of course you are working with nested tables but we won't get into that)

If this is the case then your fix would be:

```
$(nRow).addClass('a');
```

Good Luck!